# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. - Laravel-react project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, redux-thunk

Firstly, I am using react within a Laravel project and trying to list packages within Package.js component through an async call using axios through the use of an action creator. Even though I have used redux-thunk middleware, it throws an error 'Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.'. below is my code and you can even access my code in GitHub - [https://github.com/sunethice/Emerald_Tours].

index.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import { configureStore } from './store';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import './css/index.css';
import Customer from './Customer';
import Admin from './Admin';

class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Customer}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const store = configureStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
            loading="<div>Loading...</div>"
            persistor={persistor}>
            <Index/>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

store.js

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { packages } from './components/reducers';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const reducers = {
    packages,
}; 

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const configureStore = () =>
    createStore(
        persistedReducer,
        {},
        composeWithDevTools(
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )
    );
```

reducers.js

```js
import { LIST_PACKAGES, LIST_PACKAGES_FAILURE } from './actionTypes';

export const packages = (state = [], action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case LIST_PACKAGES:
            const newList = {
                packages: payload
            };
            return state.concat(newList);
        case LIST_PACKAGES_FAILURE:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

actions.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { LIST_PACKAGES, LIST_PACKAGES_FAILURE } from './actionTypes';

export function listPackages () {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('/api/packages')
          .then((res) =>{
              dispatch({type: LIST_PACKAGES ,payload:res.data});
          })
          .catch((error)=> {
              dispatch({type: LIST_PACKAGES_FAILURE, payload: error});
          })
    }
}
```

Package.js

```js
import React,{ Component, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { listPackages } from '../actions';
import pkg1 from '../../img/tour-package1.jpg';

class Package extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    render()
        {
          return (
              <div>
                  <div className="container mt-5">
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-12">
                              <div className="h3 text-center">
                                  Tour Packages
                              </div>
                              <p>
                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, curabitur nec
                                  lacus pellentesque ut facilisis, lacus iaculis
                                  turpis interdum pede, sapien quis amet vitae,
                                  erat parturient, turpis congue sit. Hac nulla
                                  phasellus ornare. Volutpat risus ipsum nulla
                                  ducimus erat. Scelerisque eu imperdiet wisi
                                  wisi, sit libero sed ipsum sodales phasellus,
                                  odio vel ac non ac, sodales viverra, metus
                                  volutpat quis rutrum diam ac integer. Posuere
                                  nullam eu vestibulum non nonummy. Metus purus
                                  ac malesuada vitae ut qui, sed rhoncus
                                  nonummy, massa ac urna risus, faucibus aliquam
                                  malesuada fusce gravida urna.
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                              <div className="btn-group">
                                  <button
                                      type="button"
                                      className="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                                      data-rel="0"
                                  >
                                      Sri Lanka
                                  </button>
                                  <button
                                      type="button"
                                      className="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                                      data-rel="1"
                                  >
                                      Maldives
                                  </button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-4">
                              <div className="travel-place">
                                  <div className="work-image">
                                      <img
                                          src={pkg1}
                                          className="img-fluid person"
                                          alt="destination"
                                      />
                                      <div className="overlay">
                                          <div className="overlay_shape">
                                              <a href="#" className="over-btn">
                                                  10 photos
                                              </a>
                                              <a
                                                  href="tourpackage.html"
                                                  className="view-all"
                                              >
                                                  View All Places
                                                  <i className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
                                              </a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="travel-text">
                                      <h3>Love City, Paris, Italy</h3>
                                      <p>
                                          for 7Days <span>|</span> $ 710.00
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          );
        }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    packages : state.packages
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchData: () => dispatch(listPackages())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(Package);
```

Much appreciate it if you can let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was nothing to do with the code. It’s something to do with the dependencies. I just typed ‘npm outdated’ to check the outdated dependecies and updated them. Then everything worked fine.